# How to make ripped/torn cloth?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I want to make a simple tear in a piece of cloth (the cloth itself was made with the cloth sim) Ideally, the torn strip should hang realistically, but I don't need it to be animated.

I'm aiming for a threadbare look, as shown below, with the little bits of string fuzz around it.

[image: cloth with holes]

I also need the torn fabric to be hanging down, not just a hole in the model/texture.

[image: cloth strips]

Is there a tool or add-on to do this "simply," other than manually modeling it? If I do have to make it by hand, how should I go about doing it?

Comment: Such effects are usually achieved with uv mapping a texture and alpha channel. It also depends on how close up your audience would see it, real close up may require some modeling.

Comment: @hawkenfox I need the torn cloth to hang down in strips; edited post to clarify my question,

Comment: @ Somatic You do realise the question you asked may require a full length tutorial right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would combine the two options above, and use use the V key to rip edges in edge select mode to outline the strips that will fall. I would still suggest alpha texture to get the edge roughing and then possibly look at the stuffed animal tutorial on CGCookie, using particles for the fuzzy stuff. Of course, the cloth sim would need to be rerun or manually unfold the strips. You might add some weight to the vertex group to make them hang.

Comment: Once I rip out the cloth strip, can I make it hang naturally by applying gravity? I looked in the Blender docs, but the only place I could find cloth gravity was in the 2.4 manual, and it seems like the feature was removed in later versions.

Comment: You should be able to weight paint it and run your simulation again to recalculate for gravity - weight painting should allow you to add weight to the strips